# How design a 5 minute down counter using counter integrated circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, counter

I'm trying to design a 5-minute countdown timer, but it has some bugs to work with. First of all (just to clarify) the last counter has its presettable start at 4 because the counter starts in 4:59.
The problem is that the second counter, every time that the last counter counts one number down, starts one "decade" lower. For example, when is 4:00 and it goes to 3:59, actually it goes to 3:49, and then it will go to 2:39 and so on.
Can anybody help me with a solution?
(The button is to start the counting)
[image]

Comment: A 5 minute countdown should start at 5:00. Otherwise it's a 4 minute 59 second countdown timer.

Comment: I can't really read the text in the diagram. Designations A to D are binary, LSB to MSB? Some LOAD terminals tied to ground comes unexpected: Shall the counter be restartable for a full 5 minutes?

Comment: Is clock 1 Hz? Preload with 300 count.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you're activating the LOAD and CLKD inputs of the middle counter at the same time. Use gates to make sure it's one or the other that becomes active.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you have a race condition concerning U2.  The CLKD (CLocK Down) input affects the RCD (Ripple Count Down) output as expected.  However, the RCD output is looped back to the LOAD input.

[image]

As seen in this image from the 40192 chip specification, there are no clock connections between these to 40192 features.  Inferring there is no synchronization.

[image]

Although the combinational logic of the 40192 and your circuit is completely described, it may not be trivial to consider all possible outcomes. Consider the CLKD input goes high decrementing the 10s of seconds value.  When CLKD goes low this causes RCD to go low if the 40192's counter is at 0b0000. This forces a load of the preset value 0b0101 into the 40192.  But changing the value of the 40192 to any non-zero value should disrupt the RCD output.  So, is the value 0b0101 successfully loaded in before the RCD output changes?  Maybe, maybe not.

Consider methods to lengthen the input LOAD low-signal-pulse to ensure the value 0b0101 is loaded into the 40192 after the RCD event but before the next CLKD event.  One method might involve a latch that is cleared by a clock source at twice the current clock's frequency.

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect, this is a pretty bad circuit, but I'll try to deal with it.

You do not identify the functionality of the counter control pins. Given what I can make out of the pin numbers, I'm guessing that the counters are CD40192s. Specifically, clear and load are asynchronous, with preset/load being active low, and reset being active high. I will note that these are very, very old ICs, going back more than 50 years.

I suspect that your reporting is incorrect. I think you mean that every time the seconds are 00, the next second the minutes count decreases by one and the seconds go to 49. I am very dubious that 3:00 goes to 2:39. I'm pretty sure that 3:00 will go to 2:49.

If I'm right, the answer is pretty clear. Let's say the counter output is 4:00. These counters are activated by the rising edge of an input clock. For a down output clock, the input clock is OR'd with the 4 outputs, so if the output is zero the output clock follows the input clock. In your circuit, when the seconds count equals 00, and the next clock pulse arrives, the left-hand output clock goes low, and this drives the middle output clock low as well. The output clock is inverted and goes high, which the NOR gate drives the load input low. This causes the middle IC to load to a 5. Because the output is no longer zero, the middle output clock goes high, and drives the right hand IC to count down by one, to 3. THEN the left-hand input clock goes high, which makes the left-hand IC count from 9 to 0. Its output clock goes high and the middle IC counts down one count to 4. The overall count is now 3:49. The next time this shows up will be at 3:00, and the count will advance to 2:49.

A first, obvious note: your left-hand counter is not set to anything when power is applied. I expect your simulation software sets it to 0, but be aware this will not be guaranteed in real life. You need to treat it the same as the other two, and load to 0 on the button push.

Frankly, this is not an easy problem with this IC, due to the asynchronous nature of the load function. You would do better doing something like letting the middle counter advance to 9, detecting that and loading the chip to 5. This will not cause any hiccups further down the line, but for a real IC you'll need to make sure that the reset pulse is long enough not to cause intermittent problems.

Now for other issues. As I say, your simulator will probably initialize your counters to zero, but this will not happen in the real world. So your counter can turn on at any value and start counting down.

And what happens when the counter reaches 0:00? As far as I can tell, it will then count to 9:59 and keep counting.

Your pushbutton flip-flop is ... bizarre. You seem to be driving clock, preset and reset simultaneously. I haven't a clue how the simulator will handle that. I'd recommend not using the clock, using the pushbutton to preset the flip-flop, use the Q output to gate the clock, then use the minutes output down clock to preset the flip flop. Then you can use the Q output to drive an LED which shows when the counter is counting down. If you do this, don't use the Q* output for anything, since it will be high whenever the counter is not counting, not just AFTER the counter stops.

Answer (score -2):

Whilst in the past I've built discrete circuits such as the one shown in the question, unless you are going into bulk production (1K units+) my advice today would be to use an arduino MPU module like the Adafruit Feathers.

This gives you total flexibility in the logic, field reprogam if needed, and nice behaviors like low voltage brown out protection / reset.

There *is* an initial ramp-up, but the longer benefits almost certainly out weighs the initial investment in time.

Even with bulk units, a custom MPU based solution (say based on the the microchip 16Fs) makes at lot of sense.

Comment: Questions like these are normally learning exercises in digital logic, not in cost-effective volume production.

Comment: Understood, but as the question didn't explicitly say it had to use digital logic, I thought it helpful to indicate the best way to solve with today's tech.

Comment: This is almost certainly an academic exercise in logic design. "best way to solve with today's tech" is completely irrelevant.